# Error Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

When I try to run this script this error appears : operating extra /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Destino/, and I do not know why , someone help me please.

```
#!/bin/bash

input="/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Output/SAIDA.txt"
dt=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`

layout='C'

if [ -e "$input" ] ; then
    header=$(head -n 1 $input)
    export header

    tail -n +2 $input | split -l 99 -d --additional-suffix=.txt \ --filter='{   printf %s\\n "$header"; cat; }' >/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Destino/$FILE - NOMENCLATURA_${dt}_

    for arquivo in ´Is/home/ubuntu/Desktop/*.txt´
    do
        NOME= ´cat $arquivo | cut -d "." -f1´
        touch/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Destino/$NOME.cfg
        echo $dt > $NOME.cfg
        echo $layout > $NOME.cfg
    done    

else
    echo "The input file does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: There are numerous errors. http://www.shellcheck.net can tell you more.

Comment: $FILE is not defined.  But, as @Biffen said, there are numerous errors that you'll have to get through.

Answer (score 2):

You have some strange quote characters in your script. To substitute the output of a command, wrap it with `$()` or backticks, not `´` characters.

```
for arquivo in ´Is/home/ubuntu/Desktop/*.txt´
```

I guess `Is` was meant to be `ls`, but you left out the space after it. But there's no need to parse the output of `ls`, just use the wildcard directly.

```
for arquivo in /home/ubuntu/Desktop/*.txt
```

On this line:

```
tail -n +2 $input | split -l 99 -d --additional-suffix=.txt \ --filter='{   printf %s\\n "$header"; cat; }' >/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Destino/$FILE - NOMENCLATURA_${dt}_
```

you need to put the output filename in quotes because of the spaces.

```
tail -n +2 $input | split -l 99 -d --additional-suffix=.txt \ --filter='{   printf %s\\n "$header"; cat; }' >"/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Destino/$FILE - NOMENCLATURA_${dt}_"
```

Also, the `FILE` variable is not set, you need to assign that earlier.

On this line:

```
    NOME= ´cat $arquivo | cut -d "." -f1´
```

you're again using the wrong type of quotes to capture the output of the command. Also, you must not have a space between `=` and the value you want to assign. It should be:

```
NOME=$(cat $arquivo | cut -d "." -f1)
```

There's no need to do `export header`. The variable is only being used in this script, not in any child processes.